# Looking for a solution to a SQL GROUP BY .... WHERE MIN date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

EDIT: The following question is angled at both MS-SQL and MySQL.

I've been pondering over this for a good 7 hours now. I've seen many stack overflow answers that are similar, but none that i've properly understood or worked out how to implement.

I am looking to SELECT id, title, e.t.c e.t.c FROM a table, WHERE the date is the next available date AFTER NOW(). The catch is, it needs to be GROUPED BY one particular column.

Here is the table:

==================================

```
 id    |    name    |    date_start    |    sequence_id
--------------------------------------------------------
  1    |   Foo1     |     20150520     |       70
  2    |   Foo2     |     20150521     |       70
  3    |   Foo3     |     20150522     |       70
  4    |   Foo4     |     20150523     |       70
  5    |   FooX     |     20150524     |       70
  6    |   FooY     |     20150525     |       70
  7    |   Bar      |     20150821     |       61
  8    |   BarN     |     20151110     |       43
  9    |   BarZ     |     20151104     |       43
```

And here is what I would like to see:

==================================

```
 id    |    name    |    date_start    |    sequence_id
--------------------------------------------------------
  1    |   Foo1     |     20150520     |       70
  7    |   Bar      |     20150821     |       61
  9    |   BarZ     |     20151104     |       43
```

The results are filtered by MIN(date_start) > NOW() AND GROUPED BY sequence_id.

I'm not entirely sure this can be achieved with a GROUP BY as the rest of the columns would need to be contained within an aggregate function which I don't think will work.

Does anyone have an answer for this dilemma?

Many Thanks!

Simon

Comment: What database are you using, SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: I didn't mention as it needs to run on both. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `join` and aggregation in a subquery:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select sequence_id, min(date_start) as minds
      from table t
      group by sequence_id
     ) tt
     on tt.sequence_id = t.sequence_id and t.date_start = tt.minds;
```

This is standard SQL, so it should run in any database.

Comment: This is perfect. The only thing missing would be "WHERE date_start > NOW() GROUP BY sequence_id". You sir are a lifesaver. I never thought of creating a nested select as the the join.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8576/4

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * 
   FROM table1
   WHERE date_start>NOW()
  ) as t2
ON t1.sequence_id = t2.sequence_id and t1.date_start>t2.date_start
WHERE t1.date_start>NOW() and t2.date_start IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.sequence_id
```

[MSSQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8576/6)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * 
   FROM table1
   WHERE date_start>GetDate()
  ) as t2
ON t1.sequence_id = t2.sequence_id and t1.date_start>t2.date_start
WHERE t1.date_start>GetDate() and t2.date_start IS NULL
```

Comment: This will not work. You have a GROUP BY on a SELECT *. MySQL will probably allow it due to it being less restrictive but it's not good practice to let the DB "guess" what rows it will pick for the GROUP BY. MSSQL will give you errors.

Comment: @simon_www that ios absolutely not a problem. But you should better choose one db server when open the question

Comment: I see the MS SQL version. I had almost this when I was working through the problem. However I didn't create a nested select as the second join (forgetting you could do that). Without the nested result set I couldn't find a way to use WHERE date_start>GetDate(). I have marked the one above as the answer as his query puts the GROUP BY in the nested select and solves both DB server problems in one statement. Thanks for your input!